# Tensor product of vectors and injective question

Tags: tensor-products

Given $v$ and $w$ vectors in $V$ we define $v_1 \otimes \dots \otimes v_n (f_1,\dots, f_n) = f_1(v_1) \dots f_n(v_n)$ with $f_i \in V^*$. Is it true that $v_1 \otimes \dots \otimes v_n (f_1,\dots, f_n) = w_1 \otimes \dots \otimes w_n (f_1,\dots, f_n) \forall f_i \implies v_h = w_h \forall h$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $v,w\in V$ be arbitrary vectors. Then
$$\forall f_1,f_2\in V^*,\quad v\otimes 0(f_1,f_2)=0=w\otimes 0(f_1,f_2).$$
But $v$ and $w$ are not necessarily equal, so the implication does not hold.

Comment: If you make $f_2,\dots,f_n = 0$, then won't every result be $0=0$?

Comment: You are absolutely right and I feel embarrassed, but I'll rewrite a solution.

Comment: good answer -- you got me to think of another similar example. If $v_1,v_2\in V$ are vectors and $\lambda\neq1$ is a scalar, then $(\lambda v_1)\otimes v_2 = v_1 \otimes (\lambda v_2)$, but certainly the individual vectors are not equal.

Comment: yup, the fundamental issue is that elements of $V\otimes V$ do not have a unique expression as a product of two vectors of $V$.